# Difference between "täglich" and "tagtäglich"

Tags: difference

Both "täglich" and "tagtäglich" means "every day". Is there any difference between the two?

From Duden:

> täglich
>
> 1. jeden Tag (vor sich gehend, wiederkehrend)
> 2. (veraltet) alltäglich

and

> tagtäglich
>
> jeden Tag ohne Ausnahme

Is it the case that "tagtäglich" stresses more strongly the fact that it's every day, without exception?

Comment: I'm bold today and like to (partially) object to what Duden says here - 'alltäglich' is not at all outdated language in standing expressions like "Der alltägliche Trott" or "Der alltägliche Berufsverkehr".

Comment: @tofro I think when Duden says "(veraltet) alltäglich", it means that this meaning is outdated, not that the word "alltäglich" is outdated. (I could be wrong, though)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are differences in usage.

*täglich* translates to *daily* and is used much the same as in English.

> Diese Zeitung erscheint täglich.
>   Die tägliche Zahnpflege sollte niemals vernachlässigt werden.

It is a neutral term that states that something happens every day or at an interval of once per day.

*tagtäglich* is similar, but has a touch of (possibly dull) routine, much like *day after day* (which could also be expressed as *Tag für Tag* in German).

> Tagtäglich macht er sich auf den beschwerlichen Weg zu seinem weit entfernten Arbeitsplatz.
>   Ihre tagtägliche Arbeit bestand darin, acht Stunden lang denselben Handgriff zu wiederholen.

Or the example from [duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tagtaeglich)

> Es war tagtäglich dasselbe.

It does emphasise that there are no exceptions (unless they are explicitly stated) and that nothing ever changes in this routine.